# Multiple read/writes to db file

Tags: python, shelve

I previously used the shelve module to write a number of files within my python based program.
However when I started to perform multiple reads and writes on the shelve objects by running multiple instances of the program I started to face a number of issues/errors.

My question is, what (if any) is the best way to perform multiple read/writes to a central file ? Or is the only way to do this is via an actual database such as MySQL ?

Thanks,

Comment: You need to do locking _someplace_.  also look into sqlite which is file based (no server) and takes care of the locking at the c level.

Comment: Ok cool, with the locking within sqlite, what happens with multi writes, do they get queued ?

Comment: Don't know, never worried about that.  The source is public domain (https://www.sqlite.org/) so you can look it up if you want;). That said, the locking is done via the existence of a lock file and there is no explicit inter-process communication so I assume when you have conflicts, each process just keeps trying until it can grab the lock to do it's thing.